# Add colons to MAC address with awk?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

Below you seen my real code, I suppose it can be simplified to

```
$ echo 123456789012 | awk '{print $1}'
123456789012
```

**Question**

How can I get `awk` to add colons, it outputs `12:34:56:78:90:12` instead?

```
grep -v '^#' $hosts | grep -E '[0-9A-F]{12}\b' | grep -v 000000000000 | awk '{
    print "host "$5" {"
    print "  option host-name \""$5"\";"
    print "  hardware ethernet "$3";"
    print "  fixed-address "$1";"
    print "}"
    print ""
}' > /etc/dhcp/reservations.conf
```

Comment: Cross site duplicate : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-insert-a-space-every-four-characters-in-a-long-line

Comment: No, this one have to be solved with `awk`.

Comment: oh, right, didn't realise `awk` was set in stone.

Comment: Just a note that 3 `grep` commands are not needed as `awk` can handle all that.

Comment: Note that these are not semicolons!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One more:

```
echo 0123456789ab | awk '{gsub(/..\B/,"&:")}1'
```

Answer (score 6):

another way

```
$ echo 123456789012 | fold -w2 | paste -sd:

12:34:56:78:90:12
```

here is a different `gawk` version

```
$ echo 123456789012 | awk -v FPAT='..' -v OFS=':' '{$1=$1}1'

12:34:56:78:90:12
```

Answer (score 3):

another way is to make use of gawk's `FIELDWIDTHS`

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 2 2 2 2 2' -v OFS=":" '1+($1=$1)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
echo 123456789012 | awk '{gsub(/../,"&:");sub(/:$/,"")} 1'
```